# PHP, document reading library

Tags: php

I need a library to extract text from documents(doc, doxc, pdf, html, rtf, odt.....). Is there one library(for all document types) for this purpose?

Comment: What kind of text? Can you please give us some more details?

Comment: The is no "One Library to bring them all and in the darkness bind them". If there was, I imagine support would be impossible; because covering all of those formats would send any group of developers insane. You won't even find **any** decent libraries for some of these document formats.

Comment: There definitely is no single library for all of these document formats. They are wildly different from each other, and have different versions representing different architectures. I'm fairly sure you will be best off looking for the optimal solution for each format.

Comment: Some PDF documents are saved as images, which would make it impossible to extract any text without also using an OCR solution (this is also possible, but of course it's another added step).

Comment: You say you want just the text, but what about formatting? Much of the text you get from some documents will be garbled or useless without the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On systems other than Windows, there is no such library to do this for you, and there is a high probability there won't be as such in the future. Main reason is that the document formats you specified are continuously updated from time to time.

On Windows however, if you have php installed, you can definitely use activex extensions to read all of these formats with ease, and you will only need the proper office application to be installed apart from php on the machine to get this to work. This will also make sure future versions of documents continue to work in your php code, as long as your office applications can read those document. Look for 'php win32' libraries in php library collections and you should find some nice one there

Comment: You've never used Linux, have you? It has lots of command line converters for different file formats...

Comment: I have used linux, but any converter you use for office files will never give 100% conversion rate... all will have few problems unless your document is plain text without any additional functionality used from the applications.

Answer (score 2):

Do batch conversions of the files to one format, using either

odtphp http://www.odtphp.com/index.php?i=tutorials&p=tutorial1

or

PyODConverter (run this using the PHP command line executable tool to make it 'work with' php) http://www.oooninja.com/2008/02/batch-command-line-file-conversion-with.html

Then run that last result through any generic pdf2txt library, or an phpOCR.

Answer (score 2):

A safer bet would be to convert your documents to plain text first, and then parse the contents of the plain text version to do whatever you want. There's a lot of command line converters around that allow you to convert from different formats to plain text ([Word to txt](http://www.winfield.demon.nl/), [PDF to txt](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/), etc.), on ANY operating system.

BTW Regarding PDFs : not all of them actually contain plain text, some are just a collection of scanned images, so in that case you'll be out of luck (unless you would use OCR on them).

Answer (score 1):

[OpenTBS](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php) is a PHP tool that can read an modify the contents of any OpenDocument files (ODT, ODS, ODG, ODF, ODM, ODP, OTT, OTS, OTG, OTP). But also OpenXML files (DOCX, XLSX, PPTX).

If you can convert files having an unsupported format you need to one of those supported by OpenTBS, then it's done.